# Delete everything between "quote" tags ([quote])

Tags: php

I have nested quotes enabled in my private message system, but now I want to show the user a part of the message when they hover the title of the message.

To get the relevant text out of the message I want to delete the quote parts.

The quote structure is as follows:

```
[quote]
  [quote]
    dasdasa adsadsa ds a
  [/quote]

  ddasd asd ads adsasd
[/quote]
```

How can I remove everything between de quote tags?

I have tried it with the following code, but the last part of the nested quotes won't remove:

```
while(preg_match('#\[quote=(.*?)\](.*?)\[\/quote\]#si', $message)) {
  $message = preg_replace('#\[quote=(.*?)\](.*?)\[\/quote\]#si', '', $message, 1);
}

while(preg_match('#\[quote\](.*?)\[\/quote\]#si', $message)) {
  $message = preg_replace('#\[quote\](.*?)\[\/quote\]#si', '', $message, 1);
}
```

Any suggestions how to delete these quotes out of the message? Thx!

Comment: Congratulations, you have experienced that regular expressions cannot be used to describe non-regular languages like your *quote* language.

Comment: But as PHP uses PCRE, not regex it still is possible.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

a) better not use regex...

b) use [recursion](http://www.php.net/manual/en/regexp.reference.recursive.php).

```
#\[quote](?:(?>[^[])|\[(?!/?quote])|(?R))*\[/quote]#
```

I haven't tested the pcre, but it should do.

Comment: Ah, I forgot that PCRE can do recursive matching.

Comment: Could you please give me an short example of a recursive code? Because I think this is not something that I learn in a couple of days, isn't it?

Answer (score 0):

There is no need to call `preg_match()`, and then call `preg_replace()`, when `preg_replace()` can replaces all strings matching the regular expression with a single call.

The problem with the regular expression you are using is that the code you reported would produce the following output:

```
  ddasd asd ads adsasd
[/quote]
```